# How to scale progressDrawable to fitxy

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Hi i need a customized seekbar

```
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/volume_bar" />
```

it works works but it is clipped

[image: clipped background]

the resource image looks like that

[image: Original background]

how can i scale the drawable into the seekbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my workaround was creating an xml drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/seekBarColor" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/seekerLineCornerRadius" />
</shape>
```